Levels in nested command buffers
I was reading the Vulkan Spec about extension VK_EXT_nested_command_buffer

Command Buffer Nesting Level
The Command Buffer Nesting Level of a secondary command buffer is equal to the maximum nesting level of all secondary command buffers executed by that command buffer plus one, where a secondary command buffer that executes no other secondary command buffers has a nesting level of zero.


VUID-vkCmdExecuteCommands-nestedCommandBuffer-09376
If the nestedCommandBuffer feature is enabled, the command buffer nesting level of each > element of pCommandBuffers must be less than maxCommandBufferNestingLevel

In the Spec, the minimum required maxCommandBufferNestingLevel limit for GPUs that support the extension is 1. So, 1 means no nesting level, correct? Therefore, a GPU can support this feature, but offer no secondary cmdbuf nesting and still comply?
